# What's the term for a word used in casual conversation that differs from its actual meaning, e.g. using "rim" to mean "wheel"

Tags: catachresis

It could be:

catachresis: A misuse of a word; an application of a term to something which it does not properly denote. e.g. Using 'rim' instead of 'wheel' is a catachresis, a misnomer used in casual conversation where 'rim' is understood to mean 'wheel' (the metal part, everything besides the tire).

solecism: An erroneous or improper usage.

Are there other terms to describe this?

Comment: Are you thinking of a phrase like "running on the rim"? If you are there's nothing wrong with that at all becasue a wheel running without a tyre has its rim in contact with the ground. The rest of the wheel, that is the hub, spokes and bearings are not in touch with the ground so the vehicle is, literally, "running on the rim".

Comment: Whether "rim" or "wheel" is a better choice depends on the context.

Comment: A mistake or **misnomer** is what it is. I don't know if there is a fancy word for one. Identifying a thing by one of its parts is called a synecdoche, but rim/wheel doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be an example of [metonymy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/metonymy):

> a figure of speech that consists of the use of the name of one object or concept for that of another to which it is related, or of which it is a part, as “scepter” for “sovereignty,” or “the bottle” for “strong drink,” or “count heads (or noses)” for “count people.”

Answer (score -1):

Well, both your words come close, in fact. However, you might want to consider ***howler***. A bit old-fashioned, if you ask me, but still up to the task:

> **howler** 3. a mistake, especially an embarrassing one in speech or writing, that evokes laughter; a very humorous mistake or a funny
> blunder.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/howler

Comment: Do you seriously think using "rim" for "wheel" would evoke laughter? I won't downvote your answer, but it's a bad answer.

Comment: @user405662: Please note the "especially" part. It means, among other things, "not always."

Comment: If an incorrect term is commonly used, it's not going to cause laughter, or indeed provoke any reaction from most people.

Comment: @Ricky "especially" only applies to "embarassing". It still has to be funny.